# ServicePoint is not unique to a local IPEndpoint

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application where I need to send 2 web requests to the same Url, but from different source IPEndpoints.

This can be done simple enough with the first connection by doing something like:

```
Dim myWebRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(MyUrl)
myWebRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = MyBindIPEndPointFunction
```

The delegate function MyBindIPEndPointFunction is called and I give it the correct IPEndpoint, everything works fine.

However on the second request, because there is already a ServicePoint for this Url, the delegate function MyBindIPEndPointFunction is not called so I do not have a way of telling the second web request to bind to a different IPEndpoint.

Because the web requests are SSL it isn't easy to just use a Net.TcpClient object instead as I'd have to handle the SSL.

Ideally I'd like way of forcing HttpWebRequest to just create a normal connection and close it once it's finished with it - without employing any ServicePoint - is this possible?  I'd also like this to all be thread safe and non-blocking so I can fire off requests in many threads (which at the moment would all use the same ServicePoint).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

could always set your endpoints in code and just create two with different variable names and the same url

```
  Private binding1 As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
  Private binding2 As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly)
Private WithEvents _Misc1 As Service_Misc.Misc_CallsClient = New Misc_CallsClient(binding1, New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61928/Misc_Calls.svc"))
Private WithEvents _Misc2 As Service_Misc.Misc_CallsClient = New Misc_CallsClient(binding2, New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:61928/Misc_Calls.svc"))
```

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, just figured I would add a potentional answer if you did not find a solution yet

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim. In the end I wrote a TCPClient and used an SSLStream object (which I had no idea existed) and I've got something working.  Your idea looks interesting though.

Comment: NO problem. Hope it helps in the future.